# Which is more efficient, Perl pattern matching or grep?

Tags: perl, grep

Which is the more efficient pattern matching on Linux systems?

Comment: When in doubt, [Benchmark](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Benchmark) it. It will depend entirely on what your regex and grep looks like, and your input, of course.

Comment: And what you use it for. `if (/foo/)` if going to be faster than the equivalent that uses the `grep` tool.

Comment: And then there's `/...(?{ ... }).../` which is just plain impossible with the `grep` tool.

Comment: @KarthikT I have experienced that string matching in perl is faster.

Comment: I've also personally found Perl to be MUCH faster for certain cases.  Also as an aside, don't forget grep has the -P flag to emulate some of Perl's syntax and power.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Russ Cox of Bell Labs wrote a great article about this in 2007. In it he shows how `grep` uses
non-deterministic finite automata to improve speed over Perl and others.

[image: perl]
[image: grep]

[Regular Expression Matching Can Be Simple And Fast](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html)

Comment: You can also change your Regex engine in Perl. See https://metacpan.org/module/re::engine::RE2

Comment: Very nice, but please correct a terminology issue: the Perl regexp engine does _not_ use DFAs. Indeed, if it did, it would match Cox's regexp just as fast as the Thompson algorithm. What Perl and the other "slow" implementations use is (a somewhat optimized form of) _backtracking_, which, technically, _is_ a method of simulating an NFA; it's just a different method than Thompson's one. (Essentially, backtracking uses a depth-first search of the state space, while Thompson's algorithm uses a breadth-first search.)

Answer (score 0):

I found the best way for me.

Before I had an array of thousands elements and grep'ped another list of thousands elements to get additional information from the array.

Now I put one time my array to array of hashes and then each time get data from it very quickly.

Was:

```
@ua1 = grep /$ip/, @ua;
```

Now:

```
$ua1[0] = $adrs{$ip};
```